# SAS user needs help! How do you join tables in R or Python from different database sources in a single SQL statement?

Tags: python, r, sas

[Be kind — my first post ever] In SAS, you can build libraries that point to different data sources like Oracle or SQL Server (or a file!). So, for example, we might have;

```
proc sql;
create table TABLE1 as
select a.student_id, a.class_standing, b.ethnicity
from STUDENT.enrollment as a left join IIR.person as b on a.id=.b.id
quit;
```

'STUDENT' is a SQL Server database and 'IIR' is an Oracle database. The SAS library setup allows us to comingle different sources in the same query.

How do you do this in R or Python? I can connect our data via both R and Python, but this integration is what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: If the tables aren't too big, you can import them into R and merge them there

Comment: You can import into R, look up the `dplyr` library `left_join` function.

Comment: If the tables *are* too big, the ```dbplyr``` package in R allows you to query/subset SQL tables using native commands from ```dplyr``` without having to import any data. If you just want to write a SQL query in RStudio, check out the ```dbGetQuery()``` function in the ```DBI``` package.

Comment: This kind of "direct" integration isn't going to be a thing in other languages for the most part - it is really one of the "killer features" of SAS, that it lets you operate on datasets from various different data sources without directly importing them.  Some classes might let you sort of handwave over that importing, or even (on a case by case basis) run code in the native language of the data source, though (which is what SAS is doing for you, just, automatically).

Comment: @Joe unless I am mistaken on what SAS is actually doing, R will do the same thing using `dbplyr`. Can't speak for Python.

Comment: @Adam SAS basically hides the interface from the user - oftentimes in fact the user is *entirely* unaware of what the underlying database is.  While SAS can expose that side of things (and for example I manage my own connections), in many environments only the DBA (or the SAS equivalent, the SAS administrator) manages the connections, and to the end user everything looks alike (a SAS dataset/library), with SAS talking to the database on demand to bring whatever is needed behind the scenes.

Comment: Gotcha, interesting to know. I think you can get the same *functionality* from R, but the connections themselves won't quite be as hidden unless some "DBA equivalent" as you say packaged it up nicely somewhere. But that usually doesn't happen - I don't think that type of feature is built out in most R implementations. You *could* do it though simply by assigning the connections to an object that looks and feels like a table. But point taken in how it may seem like a leap for a SAS user.

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can use `DBI` to connect to each SQL database and then operate on them jointly using `dplyr` with `dbplyr`. The key is to use `tbl()` to reference a table or query from a given remote connection.

I obviously can't test this, but the general idea should work. Take a look at https://db.rstudio.com/ for more details / help on connecting to your specific data sources. There is a section for SQL Server and another one for Oracle.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)

conSTUDENT <- dbConnect([YOUR CONNECTION PARAMATERS])
conIIR <- dbConnect([YOUR CONNECTION PARAMATERS])

TABLE1 <- tbl(conSTUDENT, "enrollment") %>% 
  select(student_id, class_standing, ethnicity) %>% 
  left_join(tbl(conIIR, "person"), by = c("a.id" = ".b.id")) %>% 
  # you may or may not want collect() depending on what you are doing
  # this triggers the data pull from the server
  collect()

dbDisconnect(conSTUDENT)
dbDisconnect(conIIR)
```